# Ansible archive module "no action detected in task"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to use the archive module of ansible but it is unfortunately not working. I have the following version installed: **ansible 2.3.0 (devel 2131eaba0c)**

my playbook looks like this:

```
- archive: path="{{path_dir}}" dest="{{dest_dir}}/foo.zip" format=zip
```

The output looks like this:

```
"failed": true, "reason": "no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.
The error appears to have been in '/prj/sndbox1/app/jenkins/jobs/release/workspace/tasks/build_rpclient.yml': line 125, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:

- archive: path="{{path_dir}}" dest="{{dest_dir}}/foo.zip" format=zip
  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they start a value. For instance:
    with_items:
     - {{ foo }}
Should be written as:
    with_items:
     - "{{ foo }}"
```

As far as I understood the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/modules_extra.html), the extra modules are shipped within ansible, so I assume I don't need to separately install this module.

However, what am I doing wrong? Is there any configuration I need to change in order to tell ansible where to look for the extra modules?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Included the the full log message

**Edit 2:**

I tried to put the archive.py directly into my working directory --> [library]/archive.py

Now I get the following error:

```
"failed": true, "msg": "Could not find imported module support code for archive.  Looked for either get_exception or pycompat24"
```

Comment: Is that the full playbook? What is the full error message?

Comment: I inserted the full log message. The playbook contains other tasks as well but it works without this task, so I suppose the rest of the playbook should be ok

Comment: I did some testing and it appears that archive is no longer being shipped with ansible even in 2.1.2.0. I checked my extras modules and did not see it there. You will need to grab it from the ansible git repo and place it in your playbook/role as needed.

Comment: Are you sure? I might be wrong but isn't that the module: /ansible/lib/ansible/modules/extras/files/archive.py

Comment: That is a really weird directory for your ansible install. Is that a sub-path from your python 2.7 install?

Comment: It's actually a sub directory of my user directory.

Comment: @ToniPepperoni: archive: path=/path/to/foo format=zip, remove the .zip from foo and try. In your case: archive: path="{{path_dir}}" dest="{{dest_dir}}/foo" format=zip

Comment: @techiee: That was actually the first thing I tried but it didn't work neither. The error message implies imo that something is wrong with finding the module or the module itself but thanks though.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I eventually used the shell module.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case here, I'm using **Ansible** version **2.2.0.0**. Installed via brew on MacOS sierra.

I've managed to solve the issue by adding the following into my local **ansible.cfg** file.

On defautls section, you must change the library entry:

`[defaults]
library = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.0.0_2/libexec/lib/python2.7:library`

If you have a different setup, check:

1. `pip show ansible`
2. `/usr/share/ansible` if you are on Linux machine.